Suppose that $\{f_{n}\}$ converges uniformly to $f$, and let $g_{n}(x)=f_{n}(x+1/n)$. Show that $\{g_{n}\}$ converges to $f$.
This problem is from my calculus textbook about uniform and pointwise convergence.
Problem. Suppose that $\{f_{n}\}$ converges uniformly to $f$, and let $g_{n}(x)=f_{n}(x+1/n)$. Show that $\{g_{n}\}$ converges to $f$.
I have several questions about this. For example, where is $f_{n}$ defined? On $\mathbb{R}$? What type of convergence, uniform or pointwise, do they mean when they claim $g_{n}$ "converges" to $f$? But most importantly, doesn't all the functions $f_{n}$ have to be continuous? I constructed a counterexample assuming that $f_{n}$ could be discontinuous. Set
$$f_{n}(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{rr} 1 + 1/n, & x \leq 0, \\ -1+1/n & x>0.\end{array}\right.$$
Then $\{f_{n}\}$ uniformly converges to the function $f$ given by
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{rr} 1 , & x \leq 0, \\ -1 & x>0.\end{array}\right.$$
But then $g_{n}(0) = f_{n}(1/n) = - 1 + 1/n$ which converges (pointwise) to $-1 \neq 1 = f(0)$. This means that $g_{n}(0)$ does not converge to $f(0)$, contradicting the claim of the problem. Would appreciate your thoughts on this.

I would assume "converges" means pointwise convergence because it's the weakest form of convergence. But nevertheless you are right: As stated the claim is false.
